# DocuSign embedded signing using branding

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible in the dev environment (or production for that matter) to brand the page that a user is redirected to for embedded signing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you absolutely can brand/configure the Embedded Signing iFrame window.  The way you do is, you configure your branding through the DocuSign Console, then you provide a **brandId** in your API request to chose which branding profile to use (you can save multiple).

Try logging into the DocuSign Console at demo.docusign.net and then click your profile icon in the top right and go to

```
Preferences -> Branding
```

From there you'll see that you can create and save multiple branding profiles.  Within each profile you'll see the various screens you can configure, including the signing window.  Then, in your signature API request, at the envelope level you add the property

```
brandId
```

to your JSON or XML formatted request body and make sure you provide a valid brandId for it's value.  To get a list of brand Ids programmatically, you can make the following call:

[Get Brand Profile Information](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Get%20Brand%20Profile%20Information.htm)